# execution order for twitter iframe and other javascript getting the contents of the former

Tags: javascript, iframe, twitter

I have content. They are all different (generated from widgets on Wordpress), and they all need to be pulled apart and concatenated in various ways. Basically on window.load, the javascript loops through each of the widgets, takes out the content, then puts them in clean containers in a specific order, then fades them in nicely. This works perfectly.

In comes Twitter. Twitter has a script that loads an iframe. The Twitter script is inside a widget. I'm doing the same thing, taking the contents of the widget and dumping it into a new container. This causes it such that I'm taking the Twitter script and putting it into a new container before the iframe has loaded. Somewhere along this journey, the iframe never loads. I don't want to manipulate the content inside the iframe by an means, I just want it to load in the container I choose.

My question is: is this process wrong? Or, can I get the iframe to load first, THEN grab the contents of the iframe and dump it in another container? It seems as if the iframe doesn't load until the page is loaded, but my javascript is interrupting the load process and stopping.

I'm not sure if I'm explaining this correctly, nor do I have example code that is in simplified form. Is this question answerable without these things? Thanks for the help in advance.

Edit: Taking out window.onload solved the problem. Meaning, window.load was probably interrupting the iframe from loading. However, window.load is necessary. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer to my question :

> Or, can I get the iframe to load first, THEN grab the contents of the iframe and dump it in another container?

No. Currently, there's no way to do this. [See reference](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/13264) The Twitter script was firing right away, and the window.onload was being rightfully interrupting.

The Twitter embed script is in two parts: an  element and the inline script. My workaround was to keep the script inside the javascript, and keep the  element in the widget (so the client can switch off, have multiple twitter account embeds, etc). Then, after the DOM elements are finished shuffling around and into their respective containers, I insert the script into the widget for twitter.

The iframe load, and tada! No more half-loaded twitter iframe.